# Can you apply sorting to a lists of models inside another model?

Tags: graphql, aws-amplify

Using AWS Amplify, can we apply sorting to the messages in the `Conversation` model?
When fetching the conversation, it would be nice that the messages come sorted based on the generated `createdAt` date.

Currently these are the models used.

```
type Conversation @model {
  id: ID!
  messages: [Message!]! @hasMany
  ...
}

type Message @model {
  id: ID!
  authorId: String!
  content: String!
  conversation: Conversation @belongsTo
}
```

Ideally want to place sorting on the `hasMany` directive, but this is not possible.

```
type Conversation @model {
  id: ID!
  messages: [Message!]! @hasMany(sortKeys:['createdAt'])
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a secondary index on the `Message` model with a sort field on `createdAt`.

```js
type Message @model {
  id: ID!
  authorId: String! @index(name: "byAuthorId", queryField: "getMessagesByAuthorId", sortKeyFields: [ "createdAt" ])
  content: String!
  conversation: Conversation @belongsTo
}
```

Amplify created a new query to fetch the messages and apply sorting. Following example uses react-query to fetch the messages from an `authorId` with sorting.

```js
export function useMessagesPerAuthorId({
  id,
  filter,
  enabled = true,
}: {
  id: string | undefined;
  filter: any;
  enabled?: boolean;
}) {
  return useQuery(
    ['conversations', 'messages', id, filter],
    () => fetchMessagesByAuthorId({ id: id!, filter }),
    { enabled: enabled && !!id }
  );
}

async function fetchMessagesByAuthorId({ id, filter }: { id: string; filter: any }) {
  const query: any = await API.graphql({
    query: getMessagesByAuthorId,
    variables: { authorId: id, sortDirection: 'DESC', filter },
  });

  const data: Message[] = query.data?.getMessagesByAuthorId.items;

  return data;
}
```

Now we can call that hook in our view component and pass the filters.

```js
const { isLoading, data: messages = [] } = useMessagesPerAuthorId({
    id: profile?.id,
    filter: {
      and: [{ conversationMessagesId: { eq: conversationId } }, { deleted: { eq: false } }],
    },
    enabled: !!profile?.id,
  });
```